# Location aware links

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, localization

I have a webpage that enables users to visit multiple search engine, the only thing I'd love to do next is enable location aware searches: If someone is searching from the UK, I'd like it to be the British Uk and not the greek for example.
Is there any way to detect the country the user's at using Javascript?

Comment: Agree with @mplungjan , perhaps an opt out option?

Answer (score 0):

Geolocation API:

http://html5doctor.com/finding-your-position-with-geolocation/